# is it possible to learn node.js without access to cmd.exe?

Tags: node.js, terminal

My company has locked down access to CMD.EXE (not sure why)..

I am futtzing around with Node.JS, installed it via the official Windows installer but found I have 0 access to cmd.exe and now I am wondering if I can even go about learning it with the Node terminal only?

Simple things like node -v do not work in the terminal. You have to actually do process.version.

I want to install express as another example and it does not work either.
`npm install -g express-generator`

Is there another keyword to use in place of npm when using Node.js Terminal?

Also when the Node.js terminal stops at `...` is Ctrl-D the only option to break?

Comment: If it is for learning purpose try http://runnable.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They allow you to run installers, but block access to cmd.exe? That is odd, but there are some more options.

1. Have you tried Powershell? If cmd.exe is blocked, they might have also blocked Powershell.
2. Install a third party console. Something like:

   - [console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/)
   - [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/)
   - [PowerCmd](http://www.powercmd.com/)
3. Use an IDE with built in support like [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/node.aspx)
4. Install Node on a remote server that you can SSH into (using [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) or similar tools).

   - [Free AWS Micro Instance](http://aws.amazon.com/free/)
   - [$150 / month free on Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/BIZSPARK/plus/default.aspx) if you can qualify as a startup.
   - [Cheap hosting with Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/)
   - [Free VPS with 5Jelly](http://5jelly.com/vps/) (Never used them, can't vouch for quality)
5. Ask your tech department for access (should probably be #1 :)

Answer (score 1):

When you just double-click on or execute just "node.exe" at a command prompt, you get the REPL, which is an environment that allows you to execute javascript code. It's not a regular command prompt.

Comment: > npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell.

Comment: That is correct, although you could use npm programmatically if you really want to go that far.